# swift 3: UITable cell multiple lines issue

Tags: xcode, swift3, cell

So Im attempting to create a multiple line text for the suitable cell detailedTitle however when I set the cell.numberOfLines = 0 I get multiple lines but without correct spacings for the cells. I have also tried calling cellAutoDimentions but it made no difference

```
    cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```

I Get the following result when I run that code in my program

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaFAD.png)

as you can see the text if getting pushed out of the cell's bounds in this case I'm talking about the top and bottom not the right side, that issue i know how to fix by changing the CGRect. Also the code doesn't allow for more than 2 lines

UPDATE:

The following is the entire section of my code

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itorStorage.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.messageField.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MessageCustomCell
    cell.backgroundColor = LightBlue

    cell.textLabel?.text = itorStorage[indexPath.row].name
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = itorStorage[indexPath.row].text
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = .white





    cell.pic.image = itorStorage[indexPath.row].image

    cell.timeStamp.text = itorStorage[indexPath.row].time

    cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.detailTextLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

    return cell
}



override init() {

    super.init()

    messageField.delegate = self
    messageField.dataSource = self
    messageField.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    messageField.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    messageField.allowsSelection = false

    self.messageField.register(MessageCustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    ratingView.didFinishTouchingCosmos = didTouchCosmos


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement `estimatedHeightForRowAt` as well as setting `rowHeight` to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. Something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 120.0
}
```

Comment: Could you add more of your code (especially the other tableview delegate and data source functions)? Have you implemented heightForRow? If so, remove it

Comment: Looks good as far as I can see. Can you add the estimatedHeightForRowAt function?

Comment: hey sorry for the late reply, I did add that line but still no change